# Sum for odd numbers and sum for even numbers

Tags: pseudocode

Write pseudocode of algorithm reading sequence of numbers diffrent than zero which counts sum of even and odd numbers. **(we don't know how many numbers we have to read)**<-- this part is problematic for me.
I assumed A is array.

```
ALGOR(A)
even <-- 0
odd <--- 0
for i <-- 1 to **???**
    n = A[i]
while n > 0
        do n <-- n - 2
if n = 0
    then even <-- even + n
else 
    do odd <-- odd + n
write(Odd's sum: ), write(odd), write(\n), write(Even's sum: ), write(even)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a while construct to collect your input - not a for.  Break the loop when you get something that isn't a number.